# how to access field using django signals

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I would like to check the value of a field (lightStatusA) when a new record is saved into my Django database. I feel like iv'e read the docs 10 times and still can't grasp how to get this. Here is my current models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Customer
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Data(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    tempData= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)
    humidData= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,)
    lightStatusA= models.BooleanField(default=True,) 
    dateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.author)

def check_light_status(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']: #make sure its a new record
        #need logic to grab instance.lightStatusA and check it's value

post_save.connect(check_light_status, sender = Data)
```

Is there some way of passing this value as an argument to the signal?

Answer (score 1):

The `check_light_status` function can accept an `instance` parameter.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save):

> **instance**
>   The actual instance being saved.

**Update**: You said this:

> instance returns the author of the post.

I am going to use my powers of deduction to guess that you tried `print(instance)` and saw the author. Look at your `__str__` implementation.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.author)
```

I'd say you sabotaged yourself a bit there ;)

Comment: I did this, but this instance returns the author of the post. Not sure of the syntax to call a specific field?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ok got it:

```
def check_light_status(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']: #make sure its a new record
        print(instance.lightStatusA)
```

This prints the the field I need to run some logic against.